# When MySQL table gets too large

Tags: mysql

I have a really large MySQL table counting more than 12 billion rows at the moment (table scheme: InnoDB). From time to time the problems get more and more. The biggest problem is that altering the table takes a really long time (more than 48h) and every minute downtime is one minute too much. So whenever I need to add a new index or add a new column, the problem with the altering is there.

Are 12 billion rows too much for MySQL to handle? What would you suggest to do?

Comment: I'd suggest a professionell solution e.g. Oracle DB. But the problem still could be elsewhere.

Comment: Have you thought about vertical fragmentation? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5777234/1169798

Comment: 12 billion is *really* a lot, especially for MySQL, but it also depends on your hardware and such. But even with a better server you won't get 48hrs back to 1 minute. Altering large tables in MySQL is notoriously slow.

Comment: @Janes Abou Chleih: oracle DBMS doesn't work well automagically - there should be someone to set it up properly and interact with it properly. Look at FB who uses mysql

Comment: What about postgreSQL? I have heard that you can add/remove indizes without downtime?

Comment: Incidentally, this is almost two records for every person on the planet.  Or one record for every second of the past 380 years.  What on Earth does the data represent?  Is this something that could be solved by remodelling your schema?

Comment: Do you need all that data? Archiving is not such a bad idea. eggyal does point out some scary statistics above.

Comment: @eggyal Could be financial data (12 billion ticks is not exactly THAT much), could be simulation results. Data Warehouses can have this amount of data. I Just look at a one month simulation results table (simulated order executions, we wipe the table once per month) that has - 4.5 billion rows.

Comment: @TomTom: Oh, I don't doubt that there are perfectly valid cases for so many records in a table; it's just that, in my (albeit very limited) experience, newcomers to SO who ask questions of this sort more often than not have poor DB design at the root of their troubles.

Comment: Agree. That said, it has to b a REALLY CRAPPY db design to get to 12 billion rows without having the data in the first place ;)

Comment: If you need to add a new column often, that indicates that there is a problem with the design. Can you edit the question and add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` output?

Comment: See also the answers here: [Optimizing MySQL for ALTER TABLE of InnoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654594/optimizing-mysql-for-alter-table-of-innodb), after you verify that the design is sane. The instance details (disks, memory, etc.) and configuration settings have large impact on such operations on large tables.

Answer (score 1):

48 hours ALTER to a 12 billion rows table is not out of the ordinary in InnoDB.

You could:

1. Use Percona online schema change \ Facebook php online schema change tools to ALTER the table online.
2. Switch to TokuDB engine which does these alters online and also improves performance when scaling up from InnoDB.

Both solutions are free.